# Rename a file in Tcl

Tags: tcl

from the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm#M30) it is unclear how to do so?

```
file rename ?-force? ?- -? source target
file rename ?-force? ?- -? source ?source ...? targetDir
```

> The first form takes the file or directory specified by pathname
>   source and renames it to target, moving the file if the pathname
>   target specifies a name in a different directory.

I don't see variable called pathname in function declaration.

Given a `path/to/file.csv`

How can I rename it to `path/to/renamedfile.csv` ?

```
set oldName foobar.txt
set newName bar.txt
file rename $oldName $newName
```

fails with permission denied, i guess it has to do with the file being in `C:` how can this be done?

Comment: How do you execute the script? In an interactive shell, or as a script file? Make sure that you run `tclsh` with sufficient permissions, e.g., `sudo tclsh renameScript.tcl`.

Comment: W here are you running your program from?  Is it in the same directory as the script?  If not you need to supply the full path of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see variable called pathname in function declaration.

Your interpretation of the documentation wrong. *Pathname* is a description of the *source* and *target* arguments in the function declaration.

> The first form takes the file or directory specified by (pathname)
>   *source* and renames it to (pathname) *target*...

Your code for renaming `foobar.txt` into `bar.txt` is correct. Creating and apparently also renaming files directly under `C:` requires administrator priviliges. You can get it by opening the shell (tclsh) or program with administrator priviliges, e.g. right click on icon and select "Run as administrator".

Comment: The problem ended up being the file was opened. Hence, I could not rename it.